# "Inlining" an object with Jackson Annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson

With these classes

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Foo {
    @JsonProperty
    public String bar;
}

public class Bar {
    @JsonProperty
    public Foo foo;

    @JsonProperty {
    public String baz;
}
```

I can serialize and deserialize a `Bar` instance to/from JSON objects like this one:

```json
{
  "foo": { "bar": "bar" },
  "baz": "baz"
}
```

Is there a Jackson annotation that will let me "inline" the `foo` field, so that my JSON representation becomes this?

```json
{
  "bar": "bar",
  "baz": "baz"
}
```

I'm totally OK with it throwing errors in case of naming conflicts etc, but it would be nice if I didn't have to implement a custom serializer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html):

> Annotation used to indicate that a property should be serialized "unwrapped"; that is, if it would be serialized as JSON Object, its properties are instead included as properties of its containing Object.

Your `Bar` class would look like this:

```
public class Bar {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Foo foo;

    @JsonProperty
    private String baz;
}
```

And that produces your desired output. Removing `@JsonProperty` from the field didn't seem to make a difference, so I just omitted it.